# Getting offset and back with aligned pointer in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2012, pointer-arithmetic

I'm porting an application to Visual Studio 2012 (in C++11), which currently compiles and runs correctly on gcc on several platforms.

When I tried to run it, something odd (at least to me) happened. After some moments I isolated the problem, and came up to this:

```
// This one succeeds
assert(jumper.fst == (left_prog->buffer - program->buffer));

// This one fails!
assert(left_prog->buffer == (jumper.fst + program->buffer));
```

The `program->buffer` and `left_prog->buffer` are of type `Instruction *`, and `jumper.fst` has type `ptrdiff_t`.

It wouldn't return to the original value; upon some testing, I realized that this had something to do with the aligment. My `Program` type is aligned (I've written my own allocator), and this was causing the problem. After I multiplied the aligment by `sizeof(Instruction)`, it worked as expected.

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening? Is this behaviour documented somewhere? Am I using undefined behaviour here?

(As I said, I already fixed the code by changing the aligment value, making it a multiple of `sizeof(Instruction)`, I just want to know why this happened.)

Comment: Do `left_prog->buffer` and `program->buffer` point into the same array? If not, then you have undefined behavior [expr.add.6].

Comment: Yeah, in this case they don't... I've read the C++ spec around three times already and didn't remember this one. :(